# Prevent repositional glue from sticking?

Tags: cardboard

I have a card box in which I have a card with repositionable glue on it - however the card gets stuck inside of the box, and is then fairly difficult to get out.

I wondered if anyone knew if there was anything I could coat the inside of the box with to prevent the card from sticking inside of it - preferably something long lasting. I've tried a silicone spray, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Is the glued side of the card something you need to be visible or stay sticky while inside the box, or would a solution that covers up the sticky side work? (So, fixing the card, not the whole box)?

Comment: Once the card is removed from the box, it needs to be sticky. I've considered attaching another card to that one and then removing the other said card, but because of the reason I need the sticky card in the first place, it doesn't make sense to do it (cryptic I know, haha)

Answer (score 3):

One thing that might work to reduce but not prevent sticking is sticker backing paper (waxed/plasticised). Unfortunately it's rather obvious, and not easy to attach because it's designed not to stick to glue.

Another hard to attach (I suggest staples) material is reusable non-stick cooking liner.  It's normally [brown](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reusable-Non-Stick-Cooking-Liner/dp/B00I4S4WT0) similar to much packaging cardboard, but can sometimes be found in [black](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reusable-Teflon-Cooking-stick-guarantee/dp/B001TKYTMA).  This again won't completely prevent sticking, but will make removal much easier.

These won't damage the sticky layer on the card, while one thing that probably would is wiping a very thin layer of oil/cooking spray/silicone furniture polish over spray lacquer.  This approach has the advantage of being applied like a coating, but could end up messy as well as spoiling the glue

Answer (score 0):

Well, making cardboard release is tricky. The only thing I can think of that will work well is sticker-paper backing. Buy some letter-size sticker sheets for inkjet printers. Remove the sticker,  cut the sticker backing to fit inside your box, glue the paper-side to the cardboard and then press your homemade sticker to it.

Good luck